# How to pull suppressed subscribers for a send

Tags: marketing-cloud

We did the following send:

> Job ID:   123456
>
> Name :    Email name
>
> Subject : some subject
>
> Date Sent:    22/03/2018 10:31 AM
>
> Total Sent:   15,663
>
> Data Extensions:
>
> DE Name (15663) sent
>
> (Using All Subscribers)(15663 sent)
>
> Excluded :
>
> Global Email Suppression (2143 excluded)

If you notice there are 2143 excluded records, this is because we have setup an autosuppression list. I want to get the list of 2143 subscribers with the help of query activity. I had a look at the data views but I am unable to find this information.

Can someone point me to the right data view which I should be using to get these details out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the ASL using an SQL query. Depending on how you ASL was implemented you might already have a data extension (and SQL) that automatically builds the ASL. Else you can simply query using :

```
Select 
[Email Address], 
[Date Added] 
From [Global Email Suppression] with (NOLOCK)
```

Save your results to a data extension with fields Email Address and Date Added.

Answer (score 0):

@Chandan try like this

```
select fields1,fields2 from auto suppression list name
```